# Can not make Tensorflow work with pypy3 and conda. Invalid ELF

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, conda, pypy

I want to try tensorflow inside pypy.  I tried a few days and no luck.  Following is the detail.
I am using UBuntu 18.04.
I install conda.
I install pypy through conda,  conda install -c conda-forge pypy3.6

I got No matching distribution found for tensorflow if I tried pypy3 -m pip install tensorflow

I got invalid ELF header when I run my python code if I tried pypy3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.14.0-py3-none-any.whl

I even try to install tensorflow I build but I got not a supported wheel on this platform.  The Tensorflow I build can be installed in python3.6 just not in pypy3.

I think the problem is python version different but I don't know hwo to fix it.  I notice the python version is slightly different between my python and pypy3.

I don't know how to make those two python 3.6.9 identical.  Build pypy from source myself?

(pypy3) joseph@joseph-Ubuntu:~/scripts$ python

Python 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 19:07:31)

[GCC 7.3.0] on linux

(pypy3) joseph@joseph-Ubuntu:~/scripts$ pypy3

Python 3.6.9 (5da45ced70e515f94686be0df47c59abd1348ebc, Oct 18 2019, 07:48:38)

[PyPy 7.2.0 with GCC 7.3.0] on linux

Or is there is other way to solve this problem?
Or Not to use conda?

Thanks

Joseph

Answer (score 0):

You have to somehow get tensorflow compiled for PyPy, you cannot reuse one for CPython. So far there is no binary available, and I would not advise anyone to try to recompile tensorflow, it is quite hard. So I think for now sticking with CPython for tensorflow is the best course of action.